# Email sending issue

Tags: email, gmail, stock-android

So the other day I wrote and email and it tried to send and failed with a temporary server error. Now I can't get it to stop trying to send and it doesn't show up anywhere. I sent it using the email app my stratosphere came with under my gmail account.

Comment: I think we really need some more details. Where do you see it trying to send? Did you look in the Outbox? Have you tried clearing the data for the email app?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the "Drafts" folder on both your phone and via the web interface for Gmail; if it's in there, you can just delete it.

Failing that, a reboot may clear things out.  If not, try clearing the app's cache manually by going in to `Settings->Applications->Manage Applications`, touching the `All` tab, and scrolling down to the name of your email program.  Touch it to call up the app management tools, and then touch the `Clear cache` button.  **DON'T** touch the `Clear data` button or it will delete all your account settings, too.

Comment: Email that has failed to send will sit in the "Outbox" (rather than "Drafts") until sent successfully. Whilst the web interface for Gmail doesn't actually have an _Outbox_, both the Gmail and Email Android apps do.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the "Drafts" folder on both your phone and via the web interface for Gmail; if it's in there, you can just delete it.